# Editing a Post - Django and Javascript Question

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, javascript-objects

I am new to Django and Javascript. I would like to create an edit section on a site, where people can edit a post that already exists. Similar to Facebook or Twitter.

When I click 'edit' on my post, in the console I am getting:
network.js:28 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_post/ 404 (Not Found)

I've tried many things but cannot get it to work. Any help is appreciated.
I think the issue might have to do with the use of 'post' and 'text.'
'text' is in my model, used to signify the text of the actual post.

views.py:

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def edit_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_id = request.POST.get('id')
        new_post = request.POST.get('text')
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            if post.user == request.user:
                post.text = new_post.strip()
                post.save()
                return JsonResponse({}, status=201)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({}, status=404)

    return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, 
        null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author', 
        null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)      
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,  blank=True, related_name="liked_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Javascript file:

```
edit = document.querySelectorAll(".edit");
text_area = document.querySelectorAll(".textarea");

edit.forEach((element) => {

  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    edit_handeler(element);
  });
});

text_area.forEach((element) => {
element.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey) return;
    if (e.keyCode === 13) edit_handeler(element);
  });
});

  function edit_post(id, post) {
  form = new FormData();
  form.append("id", id);
  form.append("text", text.trim());  

  fetch("/edit_post/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: form,
  }).then((res) => {
    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).textContent = post; 
    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = 
"block";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = "none";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value = text.trim();  

  });
}

function edit_handeler(element) {
  id = element.getAttribute("data-id");
  edit_btn = document.querySelector(`#edit-btn-${id}`);
  if (edit_btn.textContent == "Edit") {

    document.querySelector(`#post-content-${id}`).style.display = 
"none";
    document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).style.display = 
"block";

    edit_btn.textContent = "Save"; 
    edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-success edit");

  } else if (edit_btn.textContent == "Save") {
    edit_post(id, document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value); 

    edit_btn.textContent = "Edit";
    edit_btn.setAttribute("class", "text-primary edit");
  }
}
```

Part of html file:

```
 {% if user1 == user2 %}
                  <span class="text-primary edit" data-id="{{i.id}}" 
id="edit-btn-{{i.id}}">Edit</span>
                  <br><br>
                  {% endif %}

                  <span id="post-content-{{i.id}}" class="post" 
   {{i.post}}</span>
         <textarea data-id="{{i.id}}" id="post-edit-{{i.id}}" 
style="display:none;" class="form-control textarea" row="3">{{i.text}}</textarea>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("make_post", views.make_post, name="make_post"),
    path("fol/<str:user>", views.fol, name="fol"),
    path("following_list/<str:username>", views.following_list, 
name='following_list'),

    path('like/', views.like),
    path('edit_post/', views.edit_post),

    path("profile/<str:username>", views.profile, name="profile"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
]
```

Comment: show your urls.py

Comment: 404 error means page not found . Make sure `url` is correct .

Comment: @Swati I added the urls.py to the bottom of my post. Edit is in the middle. It seemed correct to me, matches the view etc.

Comment: You have `get('text')` in your view and `form.append("post", post.trim())` in your js code? change one of them and see if that works . Also , it goes to view or not print something there and see if it shows in terminal.

Comment: @Swati thank you, that helped. I made your revisions, using 'text' instead of 'post.' I edited the js code and html file a bit. I want to use 'text' because that is from my model. Now when I click 'edit' I get 'Uncaught reference error: text is not defined.' When I click 'edit' the textbox appears so I can actually edit the post which is good. But then I cannot save it. And I get that error in the console.

Comment: on which line does this `'Uncaught reference error: text is not defined` errors shows ?

Comment: @Swati in the function edit_post it happens in the 4th line down, in this part: form.append("text", text.trim());  And in the function edit_handeler it happens at the third line from the bottom of it: edit_post(id, document.querySelector(`#post-edit-${id}`).value);

Comment: This `form.append("text", text.trim());` should be `form.append("text", post.trim());`

Comment: @Swati if I change it to form.append("text", post.trim()); I get a similar error. Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: text is not defined. I also get an additional error, 404 not found, in the console. The text box also goes away from the page. I've also tried putting 'text' or 'post' in the other areas in this edit_post function, I've tried different combinations and I always get an error.